# Why the height of the `.container` element in the following example is `4px` instead of `0px`?

Tags: css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 0;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

While the code itself is simple, I'm unsure why the `.container` element has a height of `4px`.

When I change the display style of `.child` to `inline` or `block`, the height of `.container` becomes `0`.

Comment: You can find the live example here: https://codepen.io/y1j2x34/pen/KKxpyYE

Comment: It's because inline block elements get a space added underneath them for descenders (like text does)

Comment: @Pete - For a font-size of 12px, the space under the inline-block element will only be around 2px-3px, only a little more than half of that necessary to account for the 4px container height. Can you account for the remainder?

Comment: @Alohci depends on what the line height is set at I guess